# Android ActionBarActivity progressBar reappears with old value 100% after rotation of device

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar, progress-bar, android-orientation

I am using the Window feature progress bar to show the loading progress of two of the 6 fragments that I have. They work fine, showing from 0 to 100% and automatically hiding when reaching 100%.

When I change to one of the fragments that doesn't use it, the progress bar stills hidden but, If I rotate the device, the progress bar reappears full and never hides until I load one of the fragments that use it.

I tried putting a value of 50% during the onCreate to see if the bar reappears with a value of 50% but it doesn't, stills 100%.

I tried to change the visibility of the progress bar in each fragment but even with setProgressBarVisibility(false); in the fragment.onCreate stills showing up.

I placed breakpoints in all the functions that set the progress and no one is called during the orientation change.

**Activity onCreate:**

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_PROGRESS);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
setProgressBarVisibility(true);
```

**Function to change progress:**

```
public void setProgress(final int progress) {
    if(progress==100)
        ((MainActivity)activity).getSimulator().setBrowserLoaded(true);
    activity.runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            activity.setProgress(progress * 100);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

in your app manifest for the particular activity.

Comment: I can't, I am using retained fragments with non-serializable large objects. But thanks